# Place circular div at the center of container for all device

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

My requirement is like this:
[image]
A circular div surrounded by other 4 divs.
I tried in this way :

```css
.circle {
            z-index: 10;
            position: absolute;
            width: 13em;
            height: 13em;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background: lightblue;
            top: 60px; 
            right: 40%;
        }

        .corners {
            background: #eee;
            color: #333;
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .text {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            padding: 8px 20px 8px;
            
            height: 150px;
        }

        .arc-bottom-l,
        .arc-bottom-r,
        .arc-top-l,
        .arc-top-r {
            position: absolute;
            background: #fff;
            width: 210px;
            height: 210px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
        }

        .arc-bottom-l {
            bottom: -100px;
            left: -100px;
        }

        .arc-bottom-r {
            bottom: -100px;
            right: -100px;
        }

        .arc-top-l {
            top: -100px;
            left: -100px;
        }

        .arc-top-r {
            top: -100px;
            right: -100px;
        }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <body>

    <div class="container" style="height:300px; text-align:center;">
          <div class='circle'></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="corners col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
               
                    <div class="text"></div>
                    <div class="arc-bottom-r"></div>
                
            </div>
            <div class="corners col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6  col-xs-6">
                
                    <div class="text"></div>
                    <div class="arc-bottom-l"></div>

               
            </div>
        </div>
  <div class="row" style="height:0px"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="corners col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
                
                    <div class="arc-top-r"></div>
                    <div class="text"></div>
                </div>
            

            <div class="corners col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
                
                    <div class="arc-top-l"></div>

                    <div class="text"></div>
                </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

But i couldn't make it for all devices. How to make this thing for all devices and position the middle div accordingly?
What i tried, Adding space in between the divs and make the circular div at the center of the container but when i resize the window it get distorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close.

On `.circle` use:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

and on `.container` use:

```
position: relative
```

To make sure the circle stays in the middle regardless of screen size.

---

**Working example:**

```css
.container {
  position: relative
}

.circle {
  z-index: 10;
  width: 13em;
  height: 13em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: lightblue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.corners {
  background: #eee;
  color: #333;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 8px 20px 8px;
  height: 150px;
}

.arc-bottom-l,
.arc-bottom-r,
.arc-top-l,
.arc-top-r {
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  width: 210px;
  height: 210px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.arc-bottom-l {
  bottom: -100px;
  left: -100px;
}

.arc-bottom-r {
  bottom: -100px;
  right: -100px;
}

.arc-top-l {
  top: -100px;
  left: -100px;
}

.arc-top-r {
  top: -100px;
  right: -100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div class="container" style="height:300px; text-align:center;">
    <div class='circle'></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="corners col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-6">

        <div class="text"></div>
        <div class="arc-bottom-r"></div>

      </div>
      <div class="corners col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6  col-xs-6">

        <div class="text"></div>
        <div class="arc-bottom-l"></div>


      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="height:0px"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="corners col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-6">

        <div class="arc-top-r"></div>
        <div class="text"></div>
      </div>


      <div class="corners col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-6">

        <div class="arc-top-l"></div>

        <div class="text"></div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

```css
.circle {
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  width: 13em;
  height: 13em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: lightblue;
  top: 60px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -91px;
}

.corners {
  background: #eee;
  color: #333;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 8px 20px 8px;
  height: 150px;
}

.arc-bottom-l,
.arc-bottom-r,
.arc-top-l,
.arc-top-r {
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  width: 210px;
  height: 210px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.arc-bottom-l {
  bottom: -100px;
  left: -100px;
}

.arc-bottom-r {
  bottom: -100px;
  right: -100px;
}

.arc-top-l {
  top: -100px;
  left: -100px;
}

.arc-top-r {
  top: -100px;
  right: -100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div class="container" style="height:300px; text-align:center;">
    <div class='circle'></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="corners col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-6">

        <div class="text"></div>
        <div class="arc-bottom-r"></div>

      </div>
      <div class="corners col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6  col-xs-6">

        <div class="text"></div>
        <div class="arc-bottom-l"></div>


      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="height:0px"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="corners col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-6">

        <div class="arc-top-r"></div>
        <div class="text"></div>
      </div>


      <div class="corners col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-6">

        <div class="arc-top-l"></div>

        <div class="text"></div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```